# TF: What is the difference between the 'kernel weights' and the 'recurrent kernel weights' in LSTMs/GRUs?

Tags: tensorflow, lstm, weight-initialization, gru, glorot-initialization

**Context:**
I am trying to understand the differences between the GRU/LSTM cells from tensorflow and pytorch (for research reproducibility) and noticed that TensorFlow differentiates between the `kernel_initializer` and the `recurrent_initializer` (see documentation ([GRU](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/GRUCell)/[LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTMCell))) while PyTorch does not even mention any build in initialization (though you can overwrite the variables for custom initialization) (see torch documentation ([GRU](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.GRU.html)/[LSTM](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.LSTM.html#torch.nn.LSTM))).

**Question:**
What is the difference between `kernel weights` and `recurrent kernel weights` in LSTMs and GRUs? Why is the initialization between those different (in Tensorflow) and how would I replicate such initialization in PyTorch?